# ImportError: DLL Load Failed while importing fun: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pybind11

Hello I have started using pybind11 on windows 10 and I am not using Visual Studio.

I have followed the tutorial I have watched on YT but he was using Linux and after I created my cpp file, I cloned the pybind11 in my current directory and after that I created a build folder.

As what the guy said in the YT, I created a CMakeLists.txt in my folder with something inside:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
> project(pb11Ex)

> add_subdirectory(pybind11)
> pybind11_add_module(fun, ex_moc.pp)

Then cd to my build directory and run

```
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

Cause if I don't add it, it wont gonna generate the makefile

Then after the cmake venerated a makefile, I used

```
make
```

command giving me the file:

> fun.cp39-win_amd64.pyd

Then when I tried to import it from the python interpreter, I got this:

```
C:\Users\Nel\Desktop\python_projects\pyb11Ex\build>python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fun
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fun: The specified module could not be found
```

What does it mean by the DLL stuffs and how would I solve it?

Update:
I just followed the pybind docs

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end?